# Wordpress plugin - jquery causing page to load twice

Tags: jquery, reloading

I am writing a WordPress gallery plugin and I want to show a progress bar on file upload. My current code works and files are uploaded correctly, but after upload finishes the uploading page looks like it is loaded twice. Does anyone know what might be causing such behavior? I already managed to narrow down the problem to jQuery, without the jQuery code page reloads correctly.
Video: https://youtu.be/QDmk6xI1nK8

html:

```
<form id="image_upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Prześlij obrazek/obrazki: <br>
    <input type="file" id="upload_file" name="file_to_upload[]" multiple="multiple"><br>
    <input class="button button-primary button-large" type="submit" name="save" value="Prześlij">
    <div id="progress-div"><div id="progress-bar"></div></div>
    <div id="targetLayer"></div>
</form>
```

php:

```
if (isset ( $_FILES["file_to_upload"] ) ){

    print_r( $_FILES );


    // Count total files
    $countfiles = count($_FILES['file_to_upload']['name']);

    // Looping all files
    for($i=0;$i<$countfiles;$i++){
        if ( $_FILES['file_to_upload']['error'][$i] == 0 && $_FILES['file_to_upload']['type'][$i] == 'image/jpeg' || $_FILES['file_to_upload']['type'][$i] == 'image/png' || $_FILES['file_to_upload']['type'][$i] == 'image/gif' && $_FILES['file_to_upload']['size'][$i] <= 10485760 ){
            $filename = $_FILES['file_to_upload']['name'][$i];
            // Upload file
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_to_upload']['tmp_name'][$i], ABSPATH . '/wp-content/uploads/protex_gallery_images/'.$filename);
        }
        if ( $_FILES['file_to_upload']['error'][$i] == 1 ){
            echo "There was an error uploading image: " . print_r( $_FILES['file_to_upload']['error'][$i] );
        }
        if ( $_FILES['file_to_upload']['size'][$i] > 10485760 ){
            echo "File " . $_FILES['file_to_upload']['name'][$i] . " is too big to upload it.";
        }
        if ( $_FILES['file_to_upload']['type'][$i] != 'image/jpeg' && $_FILES['file_to_upload']['type'][$i] != 'image/png' && $_FILES['file_to_upload']['type'][$i] != 'image/gif' ){
            echo "File " . $_FILES['file_to_upload']['name'][$i] . " is not an image.";
        }
    }

}
```

jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 

    jQuery('#image_upload').submit(function(e) {
    //alert('alert working!');  
        if(jQuery('#upload_file').val()) {
            e.preventDefault();
            jQuery(this).ajaxSubmit({ 
                target:   '#targetLayer', 
                beforeSubmit: function() {
                    jQuery("#progress-bar").width('0%');
                },
                uploadProgress: function (event, position, total, percentComplete){ 
                    jQuery("#progress-bar").width(percentComplete + '%');
                    jQuery("#progress-bar").html('<div id="progress-status">' + percentComplete +' %</div>');
                },
                success: function(){

                },

        complete: function(){

        },

                resetForm: true 
            }); 
            return false;


        }
    });


});
```

Comment: Do you have any other jQuery on your page other than what is in your question?

Comment: I tested my code outside wordpress, using wamp server, and the same happens. Page does not reload and code is displayed twice. Video: https://youtu.be/SrSQUfr9o0U. I would like the page to refresh itself and display empty form.

Comment: Problem solved, it turned out that 'success' and 'complete' functions did not work. I updated jquery.form to most recent one and page reloads correctly.